# .each not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function that accepts data from push notifications and formats it into json like this:

```
{
    "sent": "02/17/2017",
    "title": "Some Entry",
    "body": "The main message here",
    "picture": "http://example.com/me.jpg",
    "phone": "555 641-6547"
}, {
    "sent": "02/13/2017",
    "title": "Some Other Stuff",
    "body": "Main content here",
    "link": "http://mycom.com",
    "phone": "555 555-6200"
}
```

As you can see they may or may not have all the name/value pairs available.

The code is meant to display a bootstrap accordian on a modal popup:

```
    function show8(arr) {
  alert('here ** ' + arr);  // lets you see incoming data

            arr = '[' + arr + ']';
            var i = 50 ;    
            var out = '';    
            out += '<div class="panel-group no_wrap widget uib_w_' + i + ' d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/accordion" data-ver="1" ';
            i++ ;
            out += 'id="bs-accordion-11">';
        $.each(JSON.parse(arr), function(idx, obj) {
            out += '<div class="panel widget uib_w_' + i + ' panel-info" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/collapsible" data-ver="1">';
            i++ ;
            out += '<div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title">';
            out += '<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#bs-accordion-group-' + i + '" data-parent="#bs-accordion-11">';
            out += '<small>' + obj.sent + '</small><br><strong><big>' + obj.title + '</strong></big><br>';
            out += '</a></h4></div>';
            out += '<div id="bs-accordion-group-' + i + '" class="panel-collapse collapse">';
            i++ ;
            out += '<div class="panel-body"><div class="col uib_col_' + i + ' single-col" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">';
            i++ ;
            out += '<div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">';
/*
            if (obj.picture.length > 0 ) {
                out += '<div class="widget uib_w_' + i + ' scale-image d-margins" data-uib="media/img" data-ver="0">';
                i++ ;
                out += '<figure class="figure-align"><img src="' + obj.picture + '"></figure></div>';
          }  
*/
            out += '<p>' + obj.body + '</p><br><br>';

/*          
    if (obj.phone.length > 0) {out += 'Call: <br><button class="btn widget uib_w_' + i + ' d-margins btn-xs btn-primary" ';
            out += 'data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" ';
            out += 'onclick= "placeCall(\'' + obj.phone + '\')">' + obj.phone + '</button><br>';}
            i++;  
            if (obj.link.length > 0) {out += 'Website: <br><button class="btn widget uib_w_' + i + ' d-margins btn-xs btn-primary" ';
            out += 'data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" ';
            out += 'onclick= "viewPage(\'' + obj.link + '\')">' + obj.link + '</button><br>';}
            i++;
*/
            out += '<span class="uib_shim"></span></div></div></div></div></div>';    
        });
        out += '</div>';

               $(".recent").html(out);
               $(".uib_w_8").modal("toggle"); 
}
```

If you uncomment any of the commented out code, the list blows up and fails to display. The if (val.length > 0) recognizes that the value is there and that it has content, but won't display the content.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `the list blows up` What does that mean? Do you get errors in the console? If so, what errors?

Comment: Sorry, it fails to display the whole list

Comment: Why are you doing this? `JSON.parse(arr)` do you stringify it somewhere else? This will fail of there is no `picture` key `if (obj.picture.length > 0 ) {` change it to: `if ((obj.picture) && (obj.picture.length > 0 )) {` - same with this, link doesn't always exist `if (obj.link.length > 0) {`

Comment: Yes, the data arrives stringified. I don't have a console on this android device, so I missed that part of the floor show! I'll give it a try and get back to you shortly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fail of there is no picture key:

`if (obj.picture.length > 0 ) {`

If you look in your console you'll see something like:

> cannot read length of undefined

change it to:

`if ((obj.picture) && (obj.picture.length > 0 )) {`

same with this:

`if (obj.link.length > 0) {`

`obj.link` doesn't always exist, change it to

`if ((obj.link) && (obj.link.length > 0)) {`

Comment: It's always the simplest things that trip you up, then make you feel stupid when all is revealed! The test for .length was supposed to see if exists. So why not just ask the question directly. Yes, I'm a newb, although I've had to work in js off and on for twenty years! It simply didn't dawn on me that if(obj.picture) is boolean. --- Thank you, Darren Sweeney!